# 404 Resource not found error with Java web service

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, jax-rs

There is a simple java webservice that i am trying to work with.

The web.xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
  <display-name>dcohandleservice</display-name> 

  <servlet>
    <display-name>JAX-RS REST Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS REST Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS REST Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

The a section of the service code is as follows:

```
@Produces("application/xml")
@Path("/handles")
@Singleton
public class HandleService {

    File privateKeyFile;

    public HandleService(){
        privateKeyFile = new File("/Users/harsha/Desktop/admpriv.bin");
        //privateKeyFile = new File("/Users/cheny18/Documents/workspace/dcoHandleApplet/admpriv.bin");
    }

    @Produces("text/plain")

    @GET
    @Path("/test")
    public String returnTestString()
    {
        return "<p>this is for testing purpose only</p>";

    }
```

When I run the web service on my local machine, the index.html loads correctly.
But when i call localhost:8080/project_name/services/handles/test
I get a 404 resource not found error.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is `project_name` the actual context path?

Comment: the project name is the name I see on eclipse.I dont think there is any issue with that.